# proper way to "observe" a promise and know when it's settled

Tags: promise, bluebird

I am using bluebird. If I have some function that returns a promise, and then I just want to return it to the caller, but I also want to "observe" and know when the promise is fulfilled to do a certain action is `reflect()` the appropriate choice to use? I do not wish to mess up the promise for the caller in any way and the caller should still be able to call any / all of `then()`, `catch()`, `error()`, `finally()`, and even `reflect()`, etc... Basically I wish to have like a middleware inbetween the caller and the function, but not mess up anything for the caller.

```
function asyncFoo() {
  const p = asyncAction();
  p.reflect().then(inspection => {
    console.log('promise p fulfilled %s', inspection.isFulfilled());
  });
  return p;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`then` is in the minimal spec, and will work just fine...

```
function asyncFoo() {
  const p = asyncAction();
  p.then(result => {
    console.log('promise p fulfilled with ${result}');
    result;
  });
  return p;
}
```

The returned promise can be treated just like the promise returned from the asynchAction.  It can have `then`, `catch`, etc invoked upon it, and it  will resolve with that async result.

Comment: Thanks that would work. I guess I didn't realize / missed the docs where it said that retuned values get wrapped in a promise.